# unreported exception.....must be caught or declared to be thrown

Tags: java, try-catch, netbeans-7

I dont understand why I am getting this error at this line:

```
Vehicle v = new Vehicle("Opel",10,"HTG-454");
```

when I put this line in a `try/catch`, I usually dont get any error but this time try/catch block doesn't work.

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
  Vehicle v = new Vehicle("Opel",10,"HTG-454");

  Vector<Vehicle> vc =new Vector<Vehicle>();
  vc.add(v);

  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  boolean test=false;
  while(!test) 
    try {
      String name;
      int i = 0;
      int say;
      int age;
      String ID;

      System.out.println("Araba Adeti Giriniz...");
      say = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

      for(i = 0; i<say; i++) {
        System.out.println("Araba markası...");
        name = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("araba yası...");
        age = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

        System.out.println("araba modeli...");
        ID = sc.nextLine();
        test = true;   

        vc.add(new Vehicle(name, age, ID));
      } 
      System.out.println(vc);
    } catch (InvalidAgeException ex) {
      test=false;
      System.out.println("Hata Mesajı: " + ex.getMessage());
    }           
  }     
}
```

and this is my constuctor in Vehicle class;

```
public Vehicle(String name, int age,String ID )throws InvalidAgeException{
        this.name=name;
        this.age=age;
        this.ID=ID;
```

Comment: check if you are passing the right values (i.e. correct data type) to the Vehicle constructor- it will help if you can post the constructor definition here

Comment: "but this time try/catch block doesnt work.." show us how you did try catch

Comment: I would also be interested to see how this even compiles as it has not an equal amount of left/right curly braces... ;) (My guess is, you are missing a `{` after `while(!test)`).

Comment: @brimborium: It doesn't, presuambly, the error message in the question title is a compile-time error.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Then my fix would help, I guess... ;)

Comment: Suggestion: use an IDE which can reformat your code and also suggest and actually do fixes to your code. At least NetBeans can, probably also Eclipse. Such an IDE can tell you exactly what exception your are not catching, and what is throwing it, and even add `try-catch` or `throws` to your code for you with just a click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>It must be</s> It's that the `Vehicle` constructor declares a checked exception. Your code calling it in `main` neither declares that checked exception nor handles it, so the compiler complains about it.

Now that you've posted the `Vehicle` constructor, we can see that it declares that it throws `InvalidAgeException`:

```
public Vehicle(String name, int age,String ID )throws InvalidAgeException{
// here ---------------------------------------^------^
```

Your `main` doesn't declare that it throws `InvalidAgeException`, and you don't have a `try/catch` around the `new Vehicle`, so the compiler won't compile it.

This is what checked exceptions are for: Ensuring that the code calling something either handles the exceptional condition (`try/catch`) or documents that it passes it on (via a `throws` clause).

In your case, you'll need to add a `try/catch` as you shouldn't have `main` declaring checked exceptions, e.g.:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
  try {
    Vehicle v = new Vehicle("Opel",10,"HTG-454");
    // ...as much of the other code as appropriate (usually most or all of it)...
  }
  catch (InvalidAgeException ex) {
    // ...do something about it and/or report it...
  }
}
```

Comment: Spot on. Question seems to be updated with Vehicle constructor, maybe update this answer to match.